# COMPASS/SASS how to interpolate a variable to @import "sprite/*.png" path?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I work on a SASS/COMPASS "framework" of my own (kind of).

I set a variable - $sprite - which is the name of the folder where all of the images are stored.

I do it this way so later I can use that name for replace-with-image-mixin and sprite generation.

Everything would be great if @import "#{$sprite}/*.png" was working.

Any ideas?

```
    //sprite images folder name
        $sprite: "sprite";

    //settings
        $sprite-sprite-base-class: ".#{$sprite}" - *works*;
        $sprite-spacing: 20px;
        $sprite-sprite-dimensions: true;

    //generate sprite
        @import "sprite/*.png"; - normal path - *works*
        @import "#{$sprite}/*.png" - path with a variable in it - *doesn't work*

    //mixin        
        @mixin replace-with-image($imageName){
            @include replace-text-with-dimensions("#{$sprite}/#{$imageName}.png");
            @extend %dis-ib;
        } - *works*
```

Comment: Looks like Compass [only supports interpolation in imports very narrowly](https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/49)

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this is simply not possible at the moment (and will never be as it looks from [the issue that steveax posted](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/49)). If you really want this, you'll have to write your own little preprocessor that resolves your variable, then outputs it to a .sass/.scss file. Alternitavely, submit a feature request...